# Iterate through multiple lists using locals in Terraform code

Tags: foreach, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, local-variables, maplist

I have the following list of Resource Group names and Virtual Machine Names, I will like to create a map using locals so I can iterate through it using each.key and each.value in my code.

VARIABLES:

```
 variable "vm_names" {
    default = [
    "vm1",
    "vm2",
    "vm3",
    "vm4",
    "vm5"
    ]

 variable "rg_names" {
    default = [
    "rg1",
    "rg2",
    "rg3",
    "rg4",
    "rg5"
]
```

LOCALS:

```
locals {
  vm = var.vm_names
  rg = var.rg_names
  vmrg=[for k,v in zipmap(local.vm, local.rg):{
    vm = k
    rg = v
  }]
}
```

RESULT:

```
 + vmrg = [
      + {
          + rg = "rg1"
          + vm = "vm1"
        },
      + {
          + rg = "rg2"
          + vm = "vm2"
        },
      + {
          + rg = "rg3"
          + vm = "vm3"
        },
      + {
          + rg = "rg4"
          + vm = "vm4"
        },
      + {
          + rg = "rg5"
          + vm = "vm5"
        },
    ]
```

DESIRED RESULT:

```
vmrg = {
            vm1 = "rg1"
            vm2 = "rg2"
            vm3 = "rg3"
            vm4 = "rg4"
            vm5 = "rg5"
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is much simpler and you were already close to figuring it out. The only thing you need is the `zipmap` built-in function:

```
vmrg = zipmap(local.vm, local.rg)
```

will yield:

```
> local.vmrg
{
  "vm1" = "rg1"
  "vm2" = "rg2"
  "vm3" = "rg3"
  "vm4" = "rg4"
  "vm5" = "rg5"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Marko E , in plain sight but I didn't see it, almost frustrated me :)